# pull path of the screen image

Tags: java, android, robotium

I'm trying to pull the path of a screen image I'm looking at on the android phone of the app im testing. The app shows various pictures. I want to pull the path of the picture to pull the picture name, but have no clue how to start. Any guidance?

edit: 
I'm trying to find out if I could pull the path from the app code to see which image the user is viewing. for example. if im looking at an image, I want to know whats the path of the image (path should be coming from someone's harddrive)

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking for. do you have the source of the application? are you white or black box testing?

Comment: srry, I'm trying to automation test scripts using robotium and java for a phone app. I'm trying to find out if I could pull the path from the app code to see which image the user is viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's not necessarily a path for an image. it's better to say the source of the image, be it a file, an HTTP stream, or otherwise. and unfortunately, that info is lost once it's set into an `ImageView`.

to set the image bits into an `ImageView`, you construct a `Bitmap`, usually using one of the `decode*()` methods in `BitmapFactory`. that is what determines the source of the image. in your unit test framework, you can get a handle to the `ImageView` by getting the `Activity` and calling `findViewById()`, but that's not going to help you.

there may be other places for you to hook into the code to determine that sources for the image data, but i can't say without knowing your application source code.

you could ask your developers to make the source available in the `ImageView`'s tag (see `setTag()` / `getTag()`). that way you could pull it out in your unit tests. of course, you'll have to have an understanding with them as to what the source will be (a URL, a database URI, a file path, ?).